# javamail access to shared mailbox

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How can I access using IMAP to shared mail box?
I have this parameters for connecting
for Example:

```
String User = "a@abc.com\sharedAccount";
String SharedMailBox = "abcMailbox";
String Password = "abc";
String Host = "abc.host.com";

Store.connect(host, 993 , (User+"/"+SharedMailBox) , Password);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific; what happens when you try and access that? Does the server you are talking to even have IMAP capabilities? What kind of error is generated? Finally, upper case letters in java for instance variables are not standard practice.

Comment: When i try to connect to my imap host it try to log in with user (composed by User+"/"+SharedMailBox)  but it fails because for log in it should have User\MailBoxShared but when it compose the string it create User\sharedaccount\abcmailbox so the format it isn't the same